# Don't Starve marking on ground question

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-together

[image: Twig-like circle on ground]

Does anyone knows what is this?

This thing won't let me put the rest of the walls. If there's no way to remove it it's ok, I'm more worried that it's a spawning spot. I didn't see it before starting my base :/

Update 1:  Its a Goose/Moose Nest. I managed to put walls there by zooming in and hovering the mouse until "place wall" text appeared. I'm gonna keep there to see if it will spawn. – Renie 6 hours ago

Update 2: it spawned even with the walls

[image: freaking moose-goose]

Comment: If you have figured out what it was, you should post your own answer rather than answering in the question

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to inform you that the object on the ground is a spawn marker, meaning it cannot be removed. I have had the same issue myself, and have tried every tool in the game to try and remove it, to no avail. Your best solution is most likely building around the spawn.

UPDATE:
After you tried placing the goose, and it placed successfully, it seems as if this could be a bug in the game, or perhaps placing the goose has less placement constraints than walls?

Comment: Update: it spawned even with the walls